# JSON in js setting value in for loop

Tags: javascript, json

I have PHP code which select values from a database.

This code is running.

```
$query = "select * from  tblUser where tag=1 and UserName='something'";

$result= mysql_query($query);
$ncrsForm[] = array();
$address[] = array();
$commDate[] = array();
$prosDate[] = array();
$x=0;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $lat[$x]=$rows['X'];
    $lng[$x]=$rows['Y'];
    $ncrsForm[$x]=$rows['NCRSFormNo'];

    $address[$x] =$rows['PlaceNo'] . " " . $rows['PlaceStreet'] . " " . $rows['PlaceBlock'] . " " . $rows['PlaceLot'] . " " .
    $rows['PlaceSubdivision'] . " " . $rows['PlaceLandmark'] . " " . $rows['PlaceBarangay'] . " " . $rows['PlaceTown'];
    $commDate[$x] = $rows['CommDate'];
    $prosDate[$x] = $rows['ProsDate'];
$x++;

}
```

After this I call the PHP variable in JS:

```
ncrsForm =<?php echo json_encode($ncrsForm); ?>;
address =<?php echo json_encode($address); ?>;
commDate =<?php echo json_encode($commDate); ?>;
prosDate =<?php echo json_encode($prosDate); ?>;
```

The code above is running. It shows the value in the database but the code below is not working. The execution stops after the code `markers.push`.. I don't know what's wrong in my code..

```
var markers[];
for (var i=0; i<address.length; i++)
{

    markers.push({
        name: "marker"+(i+1),
        ncrsForm: ncrsForm[i],
        adds: address[i],
        com: commDate[i],
        pros: prosDate[i]
        });
}
var jsOnmarkers = JSON.stringify(markers);
```

Comment: *the code below is not working.* What does it mean? Your computer burns? You have errors? You have unexpected results?

Comment: i don't know whats wrong. the execution stop after it reads the markers.push

Comment: Show an example of your ncrsForm,address,commDate and prosDate  - preferably as a jsfiddle.net

Comment: @user3799958 — So it is a JavaScript problem? Don't show us PHP then, show us the JS that gets sent to the browser. How can you tell that execution stops though?

Comment: check your console is there any errors if yes then post it here?

Comment: after i alert the ncrsForm the message box says 04141,04142,04143
same as address=asdf,adfa,aadfadsf
commDate=03Oct04,03Oct04,01Oct04
prosDate=07Oct04,07Oct04,10Jan06

Answer (score 0):

I could see array declaration is a problem in your code.

Array declaration. It should be

```
var markers = [];
```

Sample code below works fine. Try it.

```
var markers = [];
markers.push({name:'xyz', address:'abc'});
var jsonmarks = JSON.stringify(markers);
jsonmarks; // Output : "[{"name":"xyz","address":"abc"}]"
```

Comment: but i want to put it in loop